# How to undo a value assigned to a column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
people = {
        "id": [1,3,3,4]
        "city": ['A','B','C','D']
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(people)
filt = df['ID'] == 3
df['ID'] = 3
```

I had to use logical operator but used assignment operator instead.
My question is how can I undo this assignment operation and change the ID column values back to 1,3,3,4?

Comment: Original DataFrame is lost and you got only final ouput in csv? If yes, then not possible.

Comment: but not understand, if use `filt = df['ID'] = 3` and then processing `filt` it not raise error?

Comment: Actually you can't..There is no magic method exists that undo the changes...But you have to load your dataframe again(If changes not take place in your file then it is possible)

Comment: @jezrael I am sorry, I have made the changes and have edited my code. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Its better to create a new column/copy of the dataframe (`new_df = df.copy()`) for testing and when satisfied only then mutate the existing column.

Answer (score 3):

I have bad news. If original DataFrame is lost you cannot do it. So data was lost for `ID` column.

Undo operation in python not exist. You can only rerun code with original input data.