# Undo changes in pandas Dataframe(column drops, row drops, edits performed on a single cell)

Tags: python, pandas, git, version-control, dvc

I am currently working on developing a 'undo' operation for my interface that deals with changes performed on csv files. I want to provide an option for the user to revert the changes that he had done to the csv file, these changes include edit a cell, deleting column, deleting row, adding row, adding column etc. For this I want to know, does version control works in this scenario? If yes, which data version control should I prefer? If not, please suggest me an another alternative.

**EDIT: -GIT can be used for this use case**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to undo a value assigned to a column in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67057842/how-to-undo-a-value-assigned-to-a-column-in-pandas)

Comment: Yes that is true, but is it possible to use data versioning like DVC or GIT?